# Refreshing Non-Production Environments (Data Warehouse)

Tags: sql-server, database, ssis, etl, data-warehouse

My question has to do with regard to refreshing non-prod environments (Dev, Test, Staging). My question: What is typically best practice in terms of how you do it and frequency?

A couple options that I thought of:

1. Every night or periodically run the ETL jobs against their respective source environments i.e. in Dev I would go to the sources dev environment and get a refresh. This is great if the data in Dev is workable.
2. Restore a backup of production as needed.

Thanks in advance!